# Producing a small working example of a parser generator without relying on a lexer spec?

Tags: parsing, yacc, lex

Is it possible to produce a small working example of a parser generator, using yacc,  without relying on a lexer spec?
Most textbook parser specification relies on a lexer, which makes the parser example a bit complex for students to grasp (imho).

Comment: [Small working example parsers](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Examples) thanks to the Bison documentation.

Comment: @rici Thanks. But, it seems that your example does need a lexer. For example, the first one (Reverse Polish CALCulator) needs a lexer to get the token NUM. Is there a way to have a parser without a lexer?

Comment: OK, I wrote an answer. I also voted-to-close, because (as noted in the third paragraph of my answer), I don't believe that it is possible to adequately answer this question within SO's guidelines, since the question (and therefore any reasonable answer) depends on a highly-debatable opinion. Perhaps there is a formulation appropriate for [cseducators.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "without a lexer spec", you mean without generating a lexical scanner from a (f)lex specification, then you will find a number of examples of [small working parsers with hand-built lexers](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Examples) in the Bison manual. These are an important (and often neglected) resource for students and novices.

If you mean "without a lexer", then the answer is "No". Yacc (and, as far as I know, all of its commonly-used derivatives) requires that input comes from the `yylex` external function. Under normal circumstances, yacc/byacc/bison-generated parsers do not interact with `stdio` at all; they rely on `yylex` to decompose the input into tokens, and they rely on `yyerror` to dispose of error messages.

There are other parser-generators which either have lexical analysis built-in, so that there is only one specification (although it it usually distinguished into two parts), or which produce "scannerless parsers". Both of these approaches seem to have their own idiosyncracies which can be confusing to learners, but I don't believe it is possible to adequately discuss this point without violating StackOverflow's admonition against opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest case you can write a trivial lexer that just reads single character tokens from stdin:

```
int yylex() {
    return fgetc(stdin);
}
```

you then needs to write a parser that reads every character, building up larger "tokens" like numbers and identifiers as non-terminals, and explicitly skipping whitespace.  This is neither efficient nor trivial, but is a useful excercise for understanding parsing.